# Checking what fizzled sparks were supposed to do

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I've been practicing using `Control.Parallel.Strategies`, along with profiling, to try and speed up my code. However, I'm persistently finding (in one particular codebase) that I have about 10% of my sparks fizzling. Is there any way to check what those fizzling sparks were supposed to be doing? I'd like to identify the source of the fizzles so that I can program it away.

Comment: Fizzled sparks are not necessarily bad - it just means that the main thread evaluated the spark before it was evaluated in the background. More details about your program would help. I think the main concern is cpu utilization - i.e. keeping your cores busy.

Comment: ErikR: How would I check CPU utilization (other than OS utilities) in my parallel Haskell program? According to OS utilities, I'm using as much CPU as the OS can give me throughout.

Comment: You can use [threadscope](https://wiki.haskell.org/ThreadScope). If you are saturating your cpus I wouldn't worry about the fizzles.

Comment: @ErikR: Thanks - I know about threadscope, but its memory use is making it difficult for me (my profiling code generates a 3G eventlog).

Comment: Yeah - it's not suitable for large runs. Someone should write a more performant version which displays on a browser.